# Android Map View Toggle

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to toggle my map view from the standard map view to satellite. I've been given the following code by somebody on this site. But 'mMapView' is underlined in red as an error and carrying out the suggested solutions doesn't work.

Please explain to me what I'm doing wrong and what I can do right to fix this. Thanks.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.mapview :
if(mMapView.isSatellite()) {
mMapView.setSatellite(false); 
} else {
mMapView.setSatellite(true); 
}
default :
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

My onCreate is:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.map);
MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mapView.setSatellite(false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a field with the mapView and use it in the "OnOptionItemSelected". Something like this:

```
private MapView mapView;
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.map);
  mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
  mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
  mapView.setSatellite(false);
}
...
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
//this should be the id for the item in the menu, no for the map.
//if you select the item in the menu that toggle the view of your map, then, change the map
//I copied your code, but becareful because I think this can give you problems (about 
//having the same ids for the map and for the item in the same spacename ("id")
              case R.id.mapview : 
                if(mapView.isSatellite()) {
                   mapView.setSatellite(false); 
                } else {
                   mapView.setSatellite(true); 
                }
              default :
               return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
              }
            }
```

Comment: that should do the trick. I myself didn't use `onOptionItemSelected()` in my project but I don't see any problem with this piece of code

Answer (score 0):

@Finuka - This will not help the problem. It will instead cause them to have error in:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.map);
  mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
  mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
  mapView.setSatellite(false);
}
```

It should be this, which they originally used:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setSatellite(false);
}
```

I tried this in my map app. (I haven't added a toggle feature as I don't need one)

Comment: In my map app, I use the toggle feature and the code I posted, work for me. From my point of view, in the code there are two problems: one is that mMapView is not linked to the real map view. And second, the ids for the mapview and for the item in the menu are the same.

Comment: @Finuka - Missed your 'private MapView mapView;' bit out when I did it. This works on my map app, so I can confirm the initial solution works. (I just clearly don't understand how!)

Comment: well, if you dont need to modify the map after inflating it, thats why it works for you. But in case that you want to add the toggle function, the map should be accesible from every part of the class. So I put it as a field.

Comment: What do you mean after inflating it?

Comment: maybe is not the right word, but I mean when you get the view throw its id, using "findViewById"